# How to match value in if condition with concatenate

Tags: javascript, php

A JavaScript function is returning a div in double quote. like -

```
function Callback()
{
    return "<div>  <a href='javascript:void(0); >  ENGLISH </a> </div>";
}
```

I want to check if document.getElementById('language').value  == ENGLISH then apply color to ENGLISH word. So how to match JavaScript variable with concatenate.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: I think for applying color to **English** you have to first assign **class or id** to **div** or to **a** element of html. and also can you share your code to fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div id='testElem'><a href='javascript:void(0)'>ENGLISH</a></div>
<script>
  function Callback()
  {
    return "<div id='testElem'><a href='javascript:void(0)'>ENGLISH</a></div>";
  }
  function check()
  {
    if(document.getElementById('language').value == "ENGLISH")
    {
      console.log(document.getElementById("testElem").childNodes[0].style.color = 'red');
    }
  }
  check();
</script>
```

Comment: thanks. nice work for me with just change one line - $("#testElem").css("color", "red");

Answer (score 1):

```
         function Callback()
        {
            return "<div id='language'><a href='javascript:void(0);'> ENGLISH </a></div>";
        }
    var jslanguage=document.getElementById("language").textContent;
    jslanguage=jslanguage.trim() ;// will get the text ENGLISH.
if(jslanguage== "ENGLISH"){
  document.getElementById("language").style.color = "green";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want :

```
<div id="language" value="ENGLISH">
</div>

var cookieValue = document.getElementById("language").getAttribute('value');
if(cookieValue == "ENGLISH"){
  document.getElementById("language").style.color = "green";
}
```

Comment: applying color is second part. first part is how to match JavaScript variable in if condition ?